# how to select count in oracle

Tags: oracle, select, count

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpSPg.png)

how to count salary where job_title ?

I tried with coding like this, but the result error
this my code

```
select a.job_id,a.job_title,avg(b.salary) gaji_rata_rata 
from jobs a, employees b where a.job_id=b.job_id  order by job_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  a group when using aggregation function

```
select a.job_id,a.job_title,avg(b.salary) gaji_rata_rata 
from jobs a, employees b 
where a.job_id=b.job_id  
group by  a.job_id,a.job_title
order by job_id;
```